Get r (Radius) values at certain theta value for spline interpolation
I am trying to interpolate a closed spline through set of points I already have, I have gotten till here:

import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate


# Set of points I want the closed spline to pass through
x = np.array([4, 2, 0, -4, -7,-3,0,2])
y = np.array([0, 2, 3, 10, 0,-4,-3,-5])


# append the starting x,y coordinates

x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y = np.r_[y, y[0]]


# fit splines to x=f(u) and y=g(u), treating both as periodic. also note that s=0
# is needed in order to force the spline fit to pass through all the input points.


tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)


theta=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,101,endpoint=False)

Now how do I get r values of spline for given above theta values?
I know following code evaluates spline at certain evenly spaced distance values
# evaluate the spline fits for 1000 evenly spaced distance values
xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)

But I am looking to find r values for given theta values?

Splines don't have a radius parameter - that's not how they're parameterized. You could calculate the curvature, and calculate the radius as the inverse of curvature. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78194843/how-can-i-get-the-local-curvature-of-a-scipy-cubicspline Is this what you're looking for?
